# Difference between React.js and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the difference between React.js and React Native? Can they be used interchangeably? What do these things really mean?

Comment: React native is for android and ios apps, react is for websites

Comment: React _DOM_ is for websites. React is a ["UI runtime"](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/).

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS and React Native are both JavaScript frameworks/library created by Facebook for building user interfaces.

**=> ReactJS: (https://react.dev/)**

- ReactJS is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces for web applications (In short mainly used in desktop and laptops).n
- React allows developers to create reusable UI components, manage the state of these components, and efficiently update the user interface in response to changes in data or user interactions.
- React uses a virtual DOM (Document Object Model) to optimize the rendering of UI components, making web applications more efficient and responsive. (Read more about DOM here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html)

**=> React Native: (https://reactnative.dev/)**

- React Native is a framework for building mobile applications for iOS, Android, and other platforms.
- React Native allows developers to use the same codebase for multiple platforms, reducing development time and effort.
- Instead of rendering to HTML and the DOM like React.js, React Native uses native components ([Read more about Native components](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react-native-components)) to render the user interface, which results in a more native-like performance and experience.

=> **Can They Be Used Interchangeably?**

- ReactJS and React Native cannot be used interchangeably as ReactJS is designed for web browsers, while React Native is designed for mobile platforms. The code and components are not compatible between the two platforms.